# How to solve this ajax jquery error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to retrieve a string from server using ajax jquery. I have done some code. But I don't know what is the mistake. I am not getting any value when i run. Here is my code

**ReportForm.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
<script src="js\jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js\jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#btnEmployeeName').click(function () {
            var empName = $('#txtID').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetStringById',
                data: { name: empName },
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    var jqueryXml = $(data);
                    $('showName').val(jqueryXml.find('name').text());
                },
                error:function(err)
                {
                    alert(err);
                }
            })
        })   
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <center><h1>Report Form</h1>

        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Click me" id="btnEmployeeName" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtID" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="showName" />&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>
</form>
```

**EmployeeService.asmx.cs**

```
namespace NibrassSample
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET     AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class EmployeeService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public Employee GetStringById(string name)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.name = name;
            return emp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Employee.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(NibrassSample.Employee))]

namespace NibrassSample
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am new to jquery. please help me, thanks.

Comment: you have mentioned datatype as **xml**  but you are sending **json** object...i guess that must be the issue

Comment: @akshaypadwal as you said when change dataType='json' it's show error message in alert box like "localhost:60491:says [object Object]"

Comment: have you tried console.log(data) into success function of **ajax** what does it show? and also that requet is hitting your backend code?

Comment: @akshaypadwal When i enter data in textbox. it shows in console exactly the same what i type. Then i am not getting display? this is console data <Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <name>john</name>
</Employee>

Comment: @Faisal after change the dataType='json' you have to use JSON.stringify(data) to convert JSON object to string..

Comment: I got it. I did small mistake. I didn't mention '#' tag. Thank you

Comment: @Faisal, does everything work now?

Comment: @smoksnes yes my code is working. this is my mistake '$('showName').val(jqueryXml.find('name').text());' I didn't use like '$('#showName')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX call and the C# `[WebMethod]` look fine but I see in your *success* function you are trying to populate a text box with the returned value but you're not selecting it correctly in jQuery, you're doing this:

```
$('showName').val(jqueryXml.find('name').text());
```

You should put the **#** character before `showName`.In jQuery this means you're selecting the element by id:

```
 $('#showName').val(jqueryXml.find('name').text());
```